# ASP.NET MVC3 RC2 bug binding from request parameters to method parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I encounter a bug when posting values to a controller method of which one of the parameter is a nullable int.
Steps to reproduce:

I've created a test method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostTest(string from, int? number, bool? formsearch)
{
return new ContentResult { Content = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", from, number, formsearch) };
}
```

using jquery,  I create a Post request

```
$.post("http://localhost/mysite/test/posttest",{ from:"1//1/2009",number:"156",formsearch:true});
```

the request (eg. in fiddler) shows clearly the values are being sent:

from:1//1/2009
number:156
formsearch:true

but the result returned from this function is:

1//1/2009//True

If I change int? number to int number, the result is correct:

1//1/2009/156/True

In MVC3 RC1 this was working without any problems with the nullable int

Update:  I don't seem to have the problem with a newly created MVC3 website. What could I have in my project that influence model binding to nullable int's? And why would there be a difference between RC1 and RC2? Anyone have suggestions for debugging this  model binding problem?

Comment: Can't you just update the site to MVC3 RTM?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in the MVC 3 RC2 release. [ScottGu said:](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/14/update-on-asp-net-mvc-3-rc2-and-a-workaround-for-a-bug-in-it.aspx)

> we have seen a few reports of a metadata caching bug that manifests itself in at least two scenarios:
>
> - Nullable parameters in action methods have problems: When you have a controller action method with a nullable parameter (like int? – or a complex type that has a nullable sub-property), the nullable parameter might always end up being null - even when the request contains a valid value for the parameter.

The blog post I linked includes a workaround: add a line to your `Application_Start`:

```
// Workaround to fix RC2 bug with Metadata caching
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

But really you should update to the RTM. I'd be very surprised if the RC2's go-live licence survived past the RTM release.